# Parse string with XSLT containing multiple types

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, transformation

I have a string that can contain multiple codes, such as LP or 1S. I essentially need to be able to search this string for a list of values (LP|1S).

These values are always variable and if a certain code appears, then I need to sub-string after it to get additional data according to certain mapping.

For instance, after LP is the type (LP), the week (1), date, bus (0800) and location (1884).

See code below:

I was thinking of using if ... contains LP, then sub-string. However, I can only sub-string once on the text. Could I maybe use a for each and continue to sub-string until the end of the string?

```
LP12018122908001884CA212345LP120181229080018841S12345

<root>
  <entry>
   <type>LP</type>
   <week>1</week>
   <date>20181229</date>
   <location>08001884</location>
  <entry>
  <entry>
   <type>CA</type>
   <week>2</week>
   <location>212345</location>
  <entry>
  <entry>
   <type>LP</type>
   <week>1</week>
   <date>20181229</date>
   <location>08001884</location>
  <entry>
  <entry>
   <type>1S</type>
   <location>12345</location>
  <entry>
</root>
```

Comment: You need to specify which XSLT version you are using. The solution will be completely different (and much easier) with XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 than with 1.0.

Comment: Your description is not clear: can a single string contain both "LS" and "1S"? And is the length of the parameters (week, date, bus, location) fixed?

Comment: @MichaelKay ... XSLT 2.0

Comment: @michael.hor257k ... I missed this. It can contain both. And if its LP, then its 8 characters. If for instance 1S, then 6 characters.

Comment: Could we see an example of such string, with the expected result?

Comment: I updated the original post with a string containing CA and the expected output. Just it can be variable where the values LP or CA appear, but they always have the same logic after in terms of number of characters to substring.

Comment: This is confusing. First you say it's `LP` or `1S`. Now you added `CA`. Is this the final list? And can it be assumed that apart from these identifiers all the other characters will be digits?

Comment: Also you have `CA212345` in your string, but you parse out `type` as `2` and location as `212345` - where is the missing `2`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about parsing a *fixed-width* input:

This is easy to do in XSLT 2.0 using regex and `xsl:analyze-string`:

**XML**

```
<input>LP12018122908001884LP22018122908001884LP72018122908001884</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="input" regex="(.{{2}})(.)(.{{8}})(.{{8}})">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <entry>
                    <type><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></type>
                    <week><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></week>
                    <date><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/></date>
                    <location><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/></location>
                </entry>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <entry>
      <type>LP</type>
      <week>1</week>
      <date>20181229</date>
      <location>08001884</location>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <type>LP</type>
      <week>2</week>
      <date>20181229</date>
      <location>08001884</location>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <type>LP</type>
      <week>7</week>
      <date>20181229</date>
      <location>08001884</location>
   </entry>
</output>
```

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/3NzcBsL

---

To do the same thing in XSLT 1.0 is a little more complicated:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:call-template name="create-entries">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="input"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-entries">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="entry" select="substring($string, 1, 19)" />
    <entry>
        <type><xsl:value-of select="substring($entry, 1, 2)"/></type>
        <week><xsl:value-of select="substring($entry, 3, 1)"/></week>
        <date><xsl:value-of select="substring($entry, 4, 8)"/></date>
        <location><xsl:value-of select="substring($entry, 13, 8)"/></location>
    </entry>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($string) > 19">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="create-entries">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring($string, 20)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/3NzcBsL/1

Comment: Can you explain the regex? ((.{{2}})(.)(.{{8}})(.{{8}}))

Comment: @MattArthen It's rather trivial: Group 1: any character, repeated 2x; Group 2: any character; Group 3: any character, repeated 8x; Group 4: any character, repeated 8x. That's 19 characters altogether, the length of a single entry in the input string.

Comment: Gotcha! What if I'm trying to match the actual characters (such as LP) since I could have a different types (LP, 1S, 02 etc) with different requirements on what length to sub string. So if its LP substring 8, 1S substring 5 etc. Could I place them all into one group/element and then substring out later?